# Find directories excluding ending bracket ')'

Tags: find, ls

I'm trying to list all video directories (not files) which don't end in a year e.g. `(2015)` and more specifically which don't have a year listed, therefore don't end in a closing bracket `)`.

How can I do the opposite of the following:

```
# List all files and directories end with '(2015)'
ls -ld *\(2015\)

# List all files and directories end with ')'
ls -ld *\)
```

Can anyone help explain how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
ls -ld *[^\)]
```

[] - set of characters that we are interested in

^ - negation (so we include set of characters that we don't want)

\) - escaped ')'

Comment: @PaulCee: This will include non-directories too.

Comment: Since this is the accepted answer, I'll add that to fix the problem @cuonglm pointed out, one should use `ls -ldF *[^\)]/`.

Answer (score 2):

In bash or zsh:

```
for i in *; do [ -d "$i" ] && [[ ! "$i" =~ \)$ ]] && printf "%s\n" "$i"; done
```

That will simply cycle over all files and directories in the current directory and check that i) they're a directory (`[ -d "$i" ])` and ii) their name doesn't end with a `)` (`[[ ! "$i" =~ \)$ ]]`. items passing both tests will be printed.

This can deal with arbitrary file names ([which `ls` can't](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)).

Comment: @BinaryZebra both of those simply print all directories.

Comment: Maybe: (no [ -d ] test)?: `set -- *[!\)]/; for i; do printf "%s " "${i%/}";done; echo`

Comment: @BinaryZebra yes, that one should work on bourne-type shells.

Answer (score 2):

#### Method 1a:

```
ls -ld -- *[^\)]
```

(using the `[…]` pathname expansion (wildcard/glob) pattern:
`[abc]` matches `a`, `b`, or `c`;
`[^abc]` matches anything except `a`, `b`, or `c`;
so `[^\)]` matches anything except `)`.)

#### Method 2a:

```
GLOBIGNORE="*)"
ls -ld -- *
```

Pretty self-explanatory?

Both of these methods will match files
and other objects that are not directories.

---

Updated with don_crissti's suggestion, to find directories only:

#### Method 1b:

```
ls -ld -- *[^\)]/
```

#### Method 2b:

```
GLOBIGNORE="*)/"
ls -ld -- */
```

Note that you must include the `/` in the `GLOBIGNORE` value.

Answer (score 2):

Your command `ls -ld *\(2015\)` should be divided into two parts:

- The filename globbing is done by the shell. Thus, different shells may work differently.
- The ls command prints a long line `-l` for each of the filenames listed by the expansion done by the shell. Avoiding going inside directories with `-d`.

---

#### Shell

In general, this will work with all shells to produce all directories (with an added trailing /):

```
echo */                           ### disregarding effects of `-` and `\`
```

And to produce all directories that do not match an ending `)`:

[bash](/questions/tagged/bash) `echo !(*\))/`
   [ksh93](/questions/tagged/ksh93) `printf '%s ' !(*\))/`     ### avoid interpretation of `\`.
   [zsh](/questions/tagged/zsh)`echo -E ^*\)/`

With extended globbing active for bash and zsh (ksh use it by default).

```
shopt -p extglob            ### for bash (on by default in interactive use).
setopt extendedglob         ### for zsh
```

#### Remove Trailing /

```
set -- */
printf '%s ' "${@%/}"
```

Or for bash and ksh (for example):

```
set -- !(*\))/
printf '%s ' "${@%/}"
```

zsh offers a simpler way to remove trailing `\`.

```
[tag:zsh]`echo -E ^*\)(/)`
```

#### About [!\)]

Notice that above I have omitted (on purpose) the use of `[ ]`.

The use of `[!\)]` may seem equivalent (for one character):

```
echo !(*\))/
echo *[!\)]/
```

But the square brackets do not work for an string. This are **not** equivalent:

```
echo !(*\(2015\))/
echo *[!\(2015\)]/
```

However, it must be noted that `echo *[!\)]/` works for POSIX shells.

```
ls -ld -- *[!\)]/                               ### POSIXly.
```

#### Join ls and */

Depending on the shell, and if a trailing `/` is a problem or not.
The two parts `ls` and `shell` put together might be:

```
ls -ld -- !(*\(2015\))/              ### An example for bash and GNU ls.
```

#### Alternatives

The (GNU) command `ls` itself include a way to avoid patterns:

```
ls -l --ignore='*)'
```

Bash offers GLOBIGNORE:

```
GLOBIGNORE='*)/'; echo */
```

Maybe `find`?

```
find . -maxdepth 1 ! -name . -prune -type d ! -name '*2015)'
```

But find seems like overkill to me for this simple need.

Answer (score 1):

POSIXly:

```
find . ! -name . -prune -type d ! -name '*)'
```

With `zsh`:

```
print -rl -- *[^\)](/)
```

Other Bourne-like shells don't have ability to filter globbing result. You can use:

```
printf '%s\n' *[!\)]/
```

to match directories only. But it will add a trailing slash to your expansion result. With directory `foo`, you will get `foo/`.

Comment: Doesn't bash with extended globbing support negations like `ls -d !(*\))/`?

Comment: @steeldriver: the `(/)` qualifier in `zsh` is different with `/` in `ls -d !(*\))/`. And you don't need extended glob.

Comment: `find . ! -name . -prune -type d ! -name '*)'` simply worked for my purpose, thank you.

Comment: A square bracket match only one character, will not work for `(2015)`.

Comment: @BinaryZebra: how can't it work? It's not relevant to the OP question

Comment: Ah right. But it seem that the OP want exclude directories end with ) only.

Comment: The OP has, as first option: `ls -ld *\(2015\)`. And it could work with `ls -ld -- !(*\(2015\))/` (in bash for example)

Answer (score 0):

Using bash, you can use [GLOBIGNORE](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Filename-Expansion):

```
$ ls -d1 *
excludeme(2015)
excludmetoo(2016)
somedir

$ GLOBIGNORE='*)'
$ ls -d1 *
somedir
```

> GLOBIGNORE:
>
> A colon-separated list of patterns defining the set of filenames to be
>   ignored by filename expansion. If a filename matched by a filename
>   expansion pattern also matches one of the patterns in GLOBIGNORE, it
>   is removed from the list of matches.

Comment: That will also match files..

Answer (score 0):

I think find is quite appropriate for this

`find . -type d ! -regex '^.*)' -ls`

-regex '^.*)' matches all names ending with a bracket, ! inverts that,
-type d option is for dirs, 
-ls (optionally) makes output look ls-like